# How to clean up output of linux 'script' command

Tags: linux, script

I'm using the linux 'script' command  http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/script1.html to track some interactive sessions. The output files from that contain unprintable characters, including my backspace keystrokes.

Is there a way to tidy these output files up so they only contain what was displayed on screen?

Or is there another way to record an interactive shell session (input and output)?

Comment: "Or is there another way to record an interactive shell session (input and output)?" Do you know https://asciinema.org/ ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want to view the file, then you can send the output through `col -bp`; this interprets the control characters.  Then you can pipe through less, if you like.

```
col -bp typescript | less -R
```

On some systems `col` wouldn't accept a filename argument, use this syntax instead:

```
col -bp <typescript | less -R
```

Comment: on my system, `col` wouldn't accept a filename, so I did `col -bp < typescript ` and got what I wanted.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, scrambles some of the output.

Comment: On my system `less -R` by itself provides better output than piping through `col -bp` first.

Comment: @BrianHawkins I concur. Using `col -bp <typescript | less -R` does not display the colorized console. Using `less -R typescript` does display the colorized console!

Comment: this is only good if you want to view the script interactively in `less`.

Answer (score 24):

```
cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > typescript-processed
```

here's some interpretation of the string input to `perl`:

- `s/pattern//g` means to do a substitution on the entire (the `g` option means do the entire thing instead of stopping on the first substitute) input string

here's some interpretation of the regex pattern:

- `\e` match the special "escape" control character (ASCII 0x1A)
- `(` and `)` are the beginning and end of a group
- `|` means the group can match one of N patterns. where the N patterns are

  - `[^\[\]]` or
  - `\[.*?[a-zA-Z]` or
  - `\].*?\a`
- `[^\[\]]` means

  - match a set of NOT characters where the not characters are `[` and `]`
- `\[.*?[a-zA-Z]` means

  - match a string starting with `[` then do a non-greedy `.*?` until the first alpha character
- `\].*?\a` means

  - match a string that starts with `]` then do a non-greedy `.*?` until you hit the special control character called "the alert (bell) character"

Comment: I still need to figure out how, but this really works ;)

Comment: @asdmin - Basically, this echoes the output of the `typescript` to a `perl` program that removes certain control characters from the output, then pipes the output to the unix `col` command, whose `-b` option removes any "delete" key artifacts in the transcript. It then pipes the output to a text file.

Comment: This scrambles the output in the first line of the typescript for me but is the best answer.

Comment: This seems to work very well with some typescripts; it's certainly more readable than the output produced by the accepted answer.

Comment: legendary answer!

Comment: magically works for me. i'll try to include some explanation but i'm no perl guru.

Comment: Works perfectly. If you want to now extract only your input from the file run `grep '\$' typescript-processed > typescript-processed-input`. Assuming your terminal prints something like `[user@host ~]$`.

Comment: For only output do `grep --invert-match '\$' typescript-processed > typescript-processed-output`.

Answer (score 5):

I used `cat filename` which removes control characters :-)

Comment: imo this is a nicer answer, since it really removes *all* the control characters.

Comment: on OSX, cat does not remove colour control characters...

Comment: Actually cat doesn't remove the control characters at all, rather it outputs them verbatim, and the terminal then interprets them.  That might work for you if your typescript is short relative to your terminal buffer and you can just copy and paste from the terminal.  Not so good if your typescript is large though.

Comment: Agreed.  This doesn't remove anything.  It simply allows the shell to interpret them.  They are still present.

Answer (score 3):

col -bp processes the backspaces as desired (AFAIK).  But it mangles the color escape sequences.  It might be good to remove the color sequences first, then process the backspaces, if possible.

This is a very common need, and I'm surprised there are not more solutions to it.  It is extremely common to script a session, then somebody has a need to review the procedure.  You want to cut out all the little typing mistakes, and color escape sequences to create a "clean" script of the procedure for future reference.  Simple ASCII text preferred.
I think this is what is intended by "human readable", and it is a very reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

For a large quantity of `script` output, I'd hack a perl script together iteratively. Otherwise hand edit with a good editor.

There is unlikely to be an existing automated method of removing control characters from `script` output in a way that reproduces what was displayed on the screen at certain important moments (such as when the host was waiting for that *first* character of some user input).

For example the screen might be blank except for `Andrew $`, if you then typed `rm /*` and pressed backspace twelve times (far more than needed), what gets shown on the screen at the end of that depends on what shell was running, what your current `stty` settings are (which you might change partway through a session) and probably some other factors too.

The above applies to any automated method of continuously capturing input and output. The main alternative is  taking "screen shots" or cutting and pasting the screen at appropriate times during the session (which is what I do for user guides, notes for a day-log, etc).

Answer (score 2):

An answer to the second part of my question is to use the logging facility in gnu screen: `^A H` from within a running screen session. The documentation is at http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging

Answer (score 2):

**If** what you're after is to record your commands (e.g. to later turn them into a bash script), then a reasonable hack is to run `script(1)`, then inside it run

```
bash -x
```

Afterwards `grep` the output file (usually "typescript") looking for lines starting with a "+". The regular expression `^\+` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the output to a file:

```
col -bp < typescript >>newfile
```

use unix2dos command to convert file to Windows format if you want

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, that leaves in a lot of junk at the start and end of lines.  Quite readable, but not really clean.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [answer that dewtall provided](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/28887) to a similar question on the Unix board to be more effective at removing control characters from the output of script if you are in an environment where Perl is available to you.

dewtall's script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    s/ \e[ #%()*+\-.\/]. |
       \r | # Remove extra carriage returns also
       (?:\e\[|\x9b) [ -?]* [@-~] | # CSI ... Cmd
       (?:\e\]|\x9d) .*? (?:\e\\|[\a\x9c]) | # OSC ... (ST|BEL)
       (?:\e[P^_]|[\x90\x9e\x9f]) .*? (?:\e\\|\x9c) | # (DCS|PM|APC) ... ST
       \e.|[\x80-\x9f] //xg;
       1 while s/[^\b][\b]//g;  # remove all non-backspace followed by backspace
    print;
}
```

To remove the control characters:

```
./dewtalls-script.pl < output-from-script-that-needs-control-characters-removed
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/RadixSeven/typescript2txt was written to solve this problem.

It's been 4 years since I last updated/used it, but I don't remember doing anything fancy that shouldn't still work today.

Answer (score 0):

One other solution is to use [`strings`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strings) which prints only printable characters from a file (or from standard input):

```
strings -n 1 filename
```

The `-n 1` option sets the minimum length of the sequences to be preserved to one and thus makes sure even single printable characters surrounded by non-printable characters are preserved.

One possible downside of this approach is that `strings` adds line breaks between contiguous strings of printable characters. For instance a file with content

```
Foo<SOMECONTROLCHAR>Bar
```

(where `<SOMECONTROLCHAR>` is control character or any other non-printable character) would be returned as

```
Foo
Bar
```

Another issue brought up in the comments is that some sequences of control characters consist of a combination of both printable and non-printable characters and this approach would only remove part of those.

However, `strings` does a good job of removing control characters like the backspace mentioned in the question.

Comment: `strings` does not remove all non-printable characters. It identifies and prints *sequences of printable characters*. That is not the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, you're right, by default `strings` only prints sequences of a minimum length of 4. I've corrected my answer by adding the `-n 1` option which sets the minimum length to 1. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The answer still makes the same claim that `strings` removes all non-printable characters, so it is still wrong in the same way it was before the edit. It's also obviously broken because "some color code" (and control codes in general) often consist of both printable and non-printable characters. For example, a control code sequence to change the text color might be `ESC[01;52m` where `ESC` is the single escape character (byte value 27). Using `strings` as you suggest would leave `[01;52m` in the output, which is meaningless.

Comment: Good point, @MichaelKjörling. Especially the example with the color code was very unfortunate. Thanks for helping me to improve my answer. Do the edits address your concerns appropriately? `strings` might not do the same job as some of the other answers but IMHO it is a valid approach to solve the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to do it. On my system, long output lines are sprinkled with " ^M" (blank space followed by carriage return). The "^M" can be nicely replaced with the null character "^@", which does not display at all when you cat the file.

I capture timing too, so in order to replay the file perfectly, I cannot simply remove " ^M" completely using the commands below (because scriptreplay counts bytes):

```
tr '\r' '\0' | sed 's/ \x0//g'
```

I run my script command like this:

```
script -t -f session.log 2>timing
```

So, what I do afterwards is:

```
cat session.log | tr '\r' '\0' > typescript 
scriptreplay -t timing | sed 's/ \x0//g'
```

The first edit (before replay) retains the number of bytes in the file. 
The second edit (after the replay) gets rid of white space in random places. 
(Note that by default scriptreplay looks for input file named "typescript", which is why I did not provide it after "timing".)

Answer (score -1):

dos2unix on the output will also do the trick

Comment: Could you explain how to use it to accomplish the task?