# SSH on Windows 10 produces an empty log file

Tags: windows-10, ssh, logging

I am using `ssh` on Windows 10 with the -E option:

```
ssh -E log.txt myuser@myserver.com
```

The log file gets written, but it's empty. I tried ending my session with `exit` (rather than just closing the terminal window), still empty.

What I am doing wrong?

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

Comment: Just to make sure, since your don't put the whole path for the log.txt file. Are you sure you're looking at the same log.txt file? Try in the same command prompt after finishing the ssh to do `type log.txt`

Comment: perhaps you need to enable some debug logs ... one or more `-v`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, `-v` did it. (`-V` displays the version)

Comment: What I was really looking for was a way to log the user input and console output to a file: https://superuser.com/q/1260390/1725339

Comment: that's why I said `-v` not `-V` - thanks for incorrecting me